# how to change the link or image of header media in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, putty

I have hosted my wordpress website on EC2 instance AWS, i have access to the database files and phpmyadmin.

I want to change the image here at this address of the directory
"wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/images/"

I am not able to do so through filezilla, it is showing me the error of "Permission Denied"

which methods can I use to have the permission to change these files?

I have installed putty in macos as well

Comment: Maybe you don't have any Write permission to the root directory. Do you get any Error code besides "Access denied"?

Answer (score 0):

you could simply change the file permissions by right clicking to the folder and then give permission 755. once you done with your work change back original permissions then save.

Comment: Hi, I tried as you suggested but it is giving me this error in filezilla, "Error:          set attrs for /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/images/header-image.jpg.save: permission denied"